# How to put twitter timeline widget within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter

I am trying to put a twitter timeline widget (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)
within an iframe, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

And yes, I do definitely need it in an iframe.

EDIT: I realize it's normally in an iframe. I want to put that iframe within an iframe.

Comment: @ViralShah Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice. What point are you trying to make? I don't see how that relates.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you include twitter <script> inside your iframe?